# Replace or remove mutliple lines of text in oracle stored procedure

Tags: regex, oracle

Could any one help me to repalce or remove set of lines using a replace or regex replace function in oracle,and what would be the string pattern to find and replace..I need something in oracle Stored procedure

**lines to be replaced from below text**

```
</properties>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
```

**XML string**

```
<COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>global.grxml</COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>
<COLLECT_INPUTMODES>voice dtmf</COLLECT_INPUTMODES>
<CONF_INPUTMODES>dtmf</CONF_INPUTMODES>
</ROW>
</properties>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
<ROW>
<MODULE_NAME>main_menu_phone</MODULE_NAME>
<MODULE_DESCRIPTION>Main Menu for Customers with silver membership</MODULE_DESCRIPTION>
<MODULE_TYPE>phone</MODULE_TYPE>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `REPLACE` to do it.

```
 select replace('<COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>global.grxml</COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>
<COLLECT_INPUTMODES>voice dtmf</COLLECT_INPUTMODES>
<CONF_INPUTMODES>dtmf</CONF_INPUTMODES>
</ROW>
</properties>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
<ROW>
<MODULE_NAME>main_menu_phone</MODULE_NAME>
<MODULE_DESCRIPTION>Main Menu for Customers with silver membership</MODULE_DESCRIPTION>
<MODULE_TYPE>phone</MODULE_TYPE>'
,
'</properties>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
'
,'')
from dual
```

Output

```
 <COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>global.grxml</COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>
    <COLLECT_INPUTMODES>voice dtmf</COLLECT_INPUTMODES>
    <CONF_INPUTMODES>dtmf</CONF_INPUTMODES>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
    <MODULE_NAME>main_menu_phone</MODULE_NAME>
    <MODULE_DESCRIPTION>Main Menu for Customers with silver membership</MODULE_DESCRIPTION>
    <MODULE_TYPE>phone</MODULE_TYPE>
```

Answer (score 1):

The INSTR function returns the character position of a sub string within a larger string. Having found the location of some text in a string, a natural next step is to extract it, use the SUBSTR function

Or you can use replace function directly.